# Link is not matching size of image

Tags: html, css

The logo on a website I am building is an image, as you would expect, I want that image to also be a link to the homepage of the site.

The problem is that the link is covering space well past the border of the image. I know this is probably a simple fix but somewhere along the way I missed how to resolve this.

Here is the code:

```
<p><a href="http://plunderfest.muvltd.com/"><img class="aligncenter" style="border:0;" id="plunderHover" alt="" src="http://plunderfest.muvltd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/pf-final.png" width="372" height="169" /></a></p>
```

And here is the link to the site: http://plunderfest.muvltd.com

Any help would be beyond appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I just looked at your code. The problem is that the image is inside of a text-widget that doesn't have a defined width. I set the width of the text-widget to 372px and the margin to auto and that fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have the display of the image as `block` which will cause the image to take up an entire row, remove the `display block` from the image and add a `text-align: center` css to the `p` containing the image. Do this also for the `p` with the year in it.

Comment: That was it, thank you. Knew it would be something stupidly simple haha